# Django proxy model cannot be migrated when upgrading 1.4 -> 1.7

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

Having a model like below

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User # has migrations in 1.7

class MyProxyUser(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

in an app without migrations gives the following error when running the tests:

```
django.db.migrations.state.InvalidBasesError: Cannot resolve bases for [<ModelState: 'django_proxy_model_problems.MyProxyUser'>]
This can happen if you are inheriting models from an app with migrations (e.g. contrib.auth)
 in an app with no migrations; see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#dependencies for more
```

Having read both

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#dependencies
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#proxy-models

I can't figure out what I should be doing to resolve this problem (`manage.py makemigrations` reports `No changes detected`)

The problem can be reproduced by running `tox -e py27-django17` using [this github repo](https://github.com/zsoldosp/django_proxy_model_problems-with-migrations-dj17)

This can be reproduced with Django 1.7 & 1.8, but works fine with 1.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `manage.py makemigrations <app_label>`. Django won't create a migration folder if it doesn't exist, unless you explicitly specify the app label. That is because apps without migrations are (still) supported.

If the `migrations` folder exists within the app, and has an `__init__.py` file (even on Python 3), Django will pick up the app as a migrated app, and create the migrations with just `manage.py makemigrations`.

Comment: This only works if the proxy model is the only model in the module